# Isotropy groups of tetrahedron after identifying its sides

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

If we identify the 4 sides of a regular tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by letting the group of all isometries of the tetrahedron act on it, what would the resulting space look like?

The resulting space will be just a triangle with isotropy groups $\mathbb{Z}/3$ for points on its sides and the dihedral group of order 8 for the 3 vertices?

Comment: Your question is quite vague. There are many different ways to "identify the 4 sides of a tetrahedron", so I cannot tell you what the resulting space will look like because that space is not well-defined. I also have no understanding at all what object you are referring to in your last sentence.

Comment: If you can describe a specific example of how to "identify the 4 sides of a tetrahedron", then this question would become answerable.

Comment: @LeeMosher The identification will be specified by the action of its isometry group meaning that the resulting space will be the tetrahedron modulo its isometry group. 
In the last sentence I am referring to the resulting space.

Comment: What does "its isometry group" mean? Do you mean the group of all isometries of the tetrahedron? If so, that is still not well-defined, because different tetrahedra can have different isometry groups, and so you will need to tell us exactly which tetrahedron.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry about that. I am referring to a regular tetrahedron and by isometry group I mean the group of all isometries of the tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold_notation#mediaviewer/File%3aTetrahedral_reflection_domains.png) you will see that the resulting [quotient orbifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold) is a triangle with isotropy groups $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on each edge, with the order $6$ dihedral group on two of the vertices, and the order $4$ dihedral group on the remaining vertex.

Comment: Thank you.
If instead of the group of all isoetries of the tetrahedron we let the subgroup of orientation preserving isometries act on the tetrahedron the resulting space will again be a triangle orbifold with isotropy groups $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on each edge, $mathbb{Z}/3$ on two vertices and $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on one vertex?

Comment: In that case the quotient is not a triangle orbitold but instead a 2-sphere orbifold. There are no edges, or more strictly speaking the isotropy groups on any edges are all trivial. There are 3 points having nontrivial isotropy groups, and those groups are as you say.